# computing RTT problem with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to measure how long an RTT is to the server...
Here is the problem, when I have the following work it works perfectly:

```
var start = new Date();
var startTime=start.getMilliseconds();

document.write('<img src="http://mysite.com/myfile.gif" onload="getEndTime()">');


function getEndTime()
{
    var stop= new Date();
    var t=stop.getMilliseconds()-startTime;
    console.log(t);
 }
```

But if i want to store t in a variable and print it out of the function, it most of the time doesn't work!

For example:

```
var start = new Date();
var startTime=start.getMilliseconds();

document.write('<img src="http://mysite.com/myfile.gif" width="1" height="1" onload="getEndTime()">');

var rtt;

function getEndTime()
{
    var stop= new Date();
    var t=stop.getMilliseconds()-startTime;
    rtt=t;
}

console.log(rtt);
```

rtt will be 0 most of the time!!... Can anyone help? it is so frustrating!....

Comment: Try doing something before `getEndTime()`.

Comment: not sure if this is your problem, but you should define your getEndTime() function (and rtt) before you do document.write. It's possible the function is being called before it's declared.

Comment: that is not a solution :-) .. I am going to use same structure over and over in my page...

Comment: it doesn't work.. if I follow blender's suggestion, it would work most of the time... It is only the matter of the order of operations being executed...

Comment: order of operations, that's precisely what i mean. your function should be defined before you call it. you're welcome to use it as many times as you like in your app.  even if it's not your problem here, it's still good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `getEndTime` (that I can see) so how would `rtt` even be set (by the time the console.log is called).

Maybe add a button on the page or add the `console.log` after you've assigned `rtt`?

Page steps, as I see them:

1. Load up globals (start, startTime, define function, etc.)
2. Declare that you want code output to the page, and triggered on the load
3. Immediately dump the rtt (undefined) variable
4. ...
5. OnLoad *actually* triggers, but nothing is output.

---

```
var begin = new Date,
    rtt = [],
    imgs = [
        'http://myserver.com/foo.gif',
        'http://myserver.com/bar.gif'
        // etc.
    ];

function getEndTime(){
    var end = new Date;
    var delta = end.getMilliseconds() - begin.getMilliseconds();
    console.log('image loaded in ' + delta + 'ms');
    rtt.push(delta);
}
function dumpSummary(){
    // based on the number of entried in our rtt array, we can determine
    // if all the images have been loaded. if not, re-call this function (with
    // a delay until we reach it.
    if (rtt.length == imgs.length){
        console.log('All images have loaded. Their times are:');
        for (var r = 0; r < rtt.length; r++){
            console.log(r + '. ' + rtt[r]);
        }
    }else{
        console.log('waiting on more images...');
        // not enough entries, try again later
        setTimeout(dumpSummary,1000);
    }
}
// begin polling for the "finish line"
dumpSummary();

// output the images one-by-one
console.log('beginning');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
    document.write('<img src="' + imgs[i] + '" width="1" height="1" alt="" onload="getEndTime();" />');
```

Comment: @Amir: Found the error (tried to reference `start.getMilliseconds()` instead of `end.getMilliseconds()`. [works](http://jsfiddle.net/fLnuC/) for me now.

Comment: The code works perfectly, I WAS SO STUPID..  if you just define var start; in the beginning and put  start = new Date(); before document write it will work.... Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: @Amir: glad to hear it works now. ;-) And you're very welcome.

Comment: Just one last question: is it for sure that the first RTT is for the first image and so on? this is very important...

Comment: @Amir: No, but you can modify it to make it like that. e.g. make the `document.write` insert an image index in the getEndTime call. e.g. `onload="getEndTime(' + i + ')"`, then modify the getEndTime to accept an argument and use `rtt[argumentName] = delta`